# Cucumber, poltergeist strange error, while running code

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

I am getting below error while executing Cucumber test cases,

Below mentioned error details, when I execute command cucumber

```
➜  cart git:(master) ✗ cucumber
Feature: To see cart options
  Everybody should see all cart menus

  Scenario: should see menu title                          # features/cart_homepage.feature:4
    Given I am on the home page                            # features/step_definitions/homepage.rb:1
      Request to '/' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status (Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError)
      ./features/step_definitions/homepage.rb:2:in `"I am on the home page"'
      features/cart_homepage.feature:5:in `Given I am on the home page'
    When I visit homepage I should see title as Menu Items # features/step_definitions/homepage.rb:5

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/cart_homepage.feature:4 # Scenario: should see menu title

1 scenario (1 failed)
2 steps (1 failed, 1 skipped)
```

Ruby Code which is creating issues.

```
Given("I am on the home page") do
  visit "/"
end

When("I visit homepage I should see title as Menu Items") do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```

Comment: poltergeist depends on phantomjs, which is now [archived](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344). I'd recommend switching to selenium / headless chrome. As for the issue you're having, there's a relate issue [here](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/677#issuecomment-222919584). Seems a slow asset compile step was the issue for most people in the thread.

Comment: My searches led me here, and I have (tried to) switch to `Selenium / headless Chrome`, but I'm getting the same answers.